# Why window is not identifying the signature in genymotion?

Tags: genymotion

I was installing the genymotion software on my pc. During installation the genymtion, window warn against any damage to pc in future if the software installed further  and does not identify the signature.

Comment: This is because Genymotion did not digitally sign the software, so Windows cannot confirm it is a trusted publisher. It's up to you to choose if you trust Genymotion or not. Disclaimer: I work for Genymotion

Comment: Thanks for your kind suggestions. Will you please clear me that the genymotion will not cause any damage to my system?

Comment: Genymotion won't do any damage to your system, hundreds of thousands people already installed it. But be sure to download it from the official website.